# Can I make a custom pygtk tooltip stay on when the cursor is over it?

Tags: python, cursor, tooltip, pygtk, mousehover

> **Please look at the following snippet :**

```
    import gtk

    def callback(widget, x, y, keyboard_mode, tooltip):
        hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 8)
        button = gtk.Button('Exit Tooltip')
        label = gtk.Label('Tooltip text')
        hbox.pack_start(label)
        hbox.pack_start(button)
        hbox.show_all()
        tooltip.set_custom(hbox)
        return True

    label = gtk.Label('Test label')
    label.set_has_tooltip(True)
    label.connect('query-tooltip', callback)
```

Here I've created a custom **tooltip** with a ***close button*** in it. Now I want it to **stay** until i click that *close button*. Searching *google* was not that helpful. besides I would also like to know the **signals/events** that are emitted when a tooltip is being closed.

> Similar problems are handled smoothly for **JQuery/JavaScript/Ajax** tooltips etc. but
>   for **gtk/pygtk** there is no luck :(

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and as far as I know, there isn't any way to determine how long a tooltip stays up.

What I did (and recommend to you) is that you make your own "tooltip" and set it's background color to yellow, or whatever color you want, via an eventbox. Make sure you don't show it yet. This is just a simplified code, as you will need to position and size this in your project yourself.

```
color = gtk.gdk.rgb_get_colormap().alloc_color('black')
ebTooltip = gtk.EventBox()
btnTooltip = gtk.Button("Close")
ebTooltip.add(btnTooltip)
ebTooltip.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, color)
```

Now, you just need to hide and show this eventbox via your callbacks. To show it, call...

```
ebTooltip.show()
```

And, to hide it (probably on the "clicked" event of your close button)...

```
ebTooltip.hide()
```

Hope that solves your issue!

Comment: And define `enter-notify-event` and `leave-notify-event` handlers to show/hide your tooltip.